# Add element to binary tree Haskell

Tags: haskell, insert, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing the insert function of a BST, below is my code:

```
data Tree a = Empty
 | Node Integer (Tree a) a (Tree a)
 deriving (Show, Eq)

treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeInsert x Empty = Node 0 Empty x Empty
treeInsert x (Node height left a right)
 | x == a = Node height left x right
 | x < a = Node height (treeInsert x left) a right
 | x > a = Node height left a (treeInsert x right)
```

When I use my code it doesn't do anything, like the recurrence is still working

```
   tree = foldTree [1, 2, 3]
   tree
=> Node 1 (Node 0 Empty 2 Empty) 3 (Node 0 Empty 1 Empty)   
   tree = treeInsert 4 tree
   tree
```

I'm new to Haskell, could anybody help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you write `tree = treeInsert 4 tree`, you make a *cycle*, since you here define `tree` in terms of itself.

Comment: thaks it's works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing `tree = treeInsert 4 tree`, you define a new variable named `tree` that is defined in trems of itself. In Haskell all variables are immutable, so that means that once `tree` is assigned a value, you can not assign it a new value. What you can do is define a *new* variable with the same name, but then `tree` in the body of `tree = …` refers to itself.

You thus can use a new variable:

```
tree2 = treeInsert 4 tree
```

For example:

```
Prelude> tree = Node 1 (Node 0 Empty 2 Empty) 3 (Node 0 Empty 1 Empty) 
Prelude> tree2 = treeInsert 4 tree
Prelude> tree2
Node 1 (Node 0 Empty 2 Empty) 3 (Node 0 Empty 1 (Node 0 Empty 4 Empty))
```

It looks like the "height" of the nodes is not properly updated however.

Using variables in terms of itself is not uncommon in Haskell, for example you can make an infinite list of zeros with:

```
zeros = (0:zeros)
```